How can I have a check box from a filtered sheet correspond on a master sheet?
We are using google forms to submit consistent regional data.  In the linked google sheet we are filtering all the requests in to regional sheets.  So we have a master list of all submissions, and then a "view only" sheet we have formulated to divide the list into markets.  So this formula =Iferror(Filter('All Submissions'!C:BA,'All Submissions'!AA:AA="BHAM")) will only show our Birmingham, Alabama regional submissions on our BHAM sheet... What I'm running into is that when we check the box to "mark done" the record on the regional sheet we have no way of easily knowing which record it corresponds to on the Master tab for archiving. My check box lives in B on all sheets... columns C and D are unique when combined (time stamp of when the form was submitted and the users email address)... so i'd love some way for the check box in B on Sheet BHAM, notice the unique identifiers in columns C and D and correspond with the appropriate check box on the Master sheet when checked/unchecked. No idea where to start...
I have scripts for archiving the data to a different sheet when complete and deleting empty rows, I really just want the check box to work to help reduce manual load.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
